# Way to add hotkeys to focus on specific windows with same title?

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys, setfocus

I have a situation with 2-5 windows with the same name. I want to set hotkeys for each window so I can press the hotkey and get focus on the specific window the hotkey is assigned to. I'm told I can do this with AutoHotkey but I can't find how it distinguishes windows if they have the same name.
For reference this is a game so I don't think there is any text internally it could search for. Any thoughts?

Comment: What about the place/coordinares the height and the width of those windows? What other infos can you get from Window Spy?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using the windows' HWND is pretty much always the solution here.
The easiest implementation would be to "manually" grab the hwnd's for each window:

```
^1::Window1 := WinActive("A")
^2::Window2 := WinActive("A")
^3::Window3 := WinActive("A")

1::WinActivate, % "ahk_id " Window1
2::WinActivate, % "ahk_id " Window2
3::WinActivate, % "ahk_id " Window3
```

With this you'd press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> on the first window to store its HWND, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> on the second, etc.
And after that you can use the hotkeys `1`, `2` and `3` to activate those windows.

This manual approach is of course quite low-tech, but for situations like these, it's probably just what you want.
It can be quite hard to automatically tell apart duplicate windows.
I can't even begin to write some automatic code for you, since I couldn't know what windows you're trying to tell apart and how.
But you'd probably want to start from looping the result from `WinGet, , List`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGet.htm#List)</sup>.